# Differences between the following python and ruby code

Tags: python, ruby

I was trying to solve the following problem: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/23/

This was my solution in Python, which didn't pass:

```
for x in range(1,13):
    string = ''
    for y in range(1,13):
        string += ' '*(4-len(str(x*y))) + str(x*y)
    print string.strip()
```

This was my friend's solution in Ruby, which did pass:

```
for i in 1..12
  line = ""
  for j in 1..12
    line += " " * (4 - (j * i).to_s.length) + "#{j * i}"
  end
  puts line.strip
end
```

To me, the two snippets look like they do the same thing and they output the same thing based on my testing. Do you think there is a reason my solution isn't being accepted other than issues with the evaluation system?

Comment: don't call a string `string` and use string formatting to align stuff

Comment: The output is exactly the same..

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but may be because better way of writing code in Python is something like  that @Martijn's answered

Comment: `for i in 1..12` is almost always better written as `12.times do |i|` or `(1..12).each do |i|` as it's extremely unusual to see `for` used in Ruby code.

Comment: Btw, Who submitted first? you or your friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
for x in range(1, 13):
    print ''.join([format(x * y, '2d' if y == 1 else '4d') 
                   for y in range(1, 13)])
```

This formats the left-most column to hold at most 2 characters (1 through to 12), 4 characters otherwise, right-aligned.

Your version removes too much whitespace from the start of the lines; the last 3 lines need space for 2 digits in the left-most column.

Comment: But so does the ruby version, which was apparently accepted.

Comment: @wim: I don't know enough Ruby to judge that, but it could be that there is a bug in the challenge checker for Ruby.

Comment: @wim: another option is that the friend is pulling OPs leg and hasn't yet passed the challenge.

Comment: No I tried to submit the Ruby solution and it did pass. Thank you for the suggested approach though. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in Ruby for comparison:

```
(1..12).each do |i|
  puts((1..12).collect do |j|
    '%4d' % (i * j)
  end.join(' '))
end
```

The `'%4d'` makes use of `sprintf`-style formatting to properly pad without needing to test lengths.